# Vue.js 3 SFC multiple lists

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props, vue-script-setup, vue-sfc

I am creating a vue.js3 SFC application where the list component is used multiple times. The aim is to produse a separate lists of items in each component from SingleList.vue. I wanted to use a v-for='item in items'.

When I add the unordered list in SingleList.vue, and keep the const's defined in App.vue, my card is multiplied and each list item is shown in a single card.

On the other hand if I do as presented (and add the ul in the App.vue), no items are listed. I feel like I am missing a step or two but cant find what is that.

I have no error or warning in the console, but cannot grasp the idea of list rendering when there is more than one element.

What I have at the moment can be viewed under the following link: [LINK](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Could anyone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the list items in the parent can be done using a default [slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slots). You just need to utilize the special `<slot />` element in the child component which the parent HTML will replace.

**SingleList.vue**

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text">
    <slot />
  </p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you also have a `uList` prop in SingleList.vue which it looks like you were maybe thinking of using to accept the list of items from the parent? You can do that too.  This way you do all the list rendering in the child component and *not* the parent.

**App.vue**

```html
<SingleList header="One" :u-list="itemsOne">
</SingleList>
```

**SingleList.vue**

```js
defineProps({
  ...
  uList: {
    type: Object
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in uList" :key="item.id">{{ item.label }}</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

I modified your [Vue Playground demo](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) to show both strategies.